# How to change color of single letters or one word in line

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

How to change color of word in "message" in AlertView

```
@@IBAction func btn_instructions(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertView = UNAlertView(title: "MyTitle", message: "Here green text, here red text")
 alertView.show()
```

Sorry if question is not correct.

Comment: Note that `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS9 (I assume `UNAlertView` above is a typo). You should make use of `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: @LeoDabus It does, actually, have attributed text properties, `"attributedTitle"` and `"attributedMessage"` for title and message text, respectively. However, as far as I can find, these are undocumented by Apple; I can only find them referenced as derived by users via [runtime introspection](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertController.h).

Comment: Does UIAlertAction also have "attributedTitle" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've written in my comment above, `UIAlertView` is deprecated, so you'll have to use `UIAlertController` instead. You *can*, however, set attributed strings for the message, using  (non-swifty) key-value coding (since `UIAlertView` is a subclass of `NSObject`): setting an attributed string for key `"attributedMessage"`. The associated key for the title is `"attributedTitle"`.

Note, however, that these features seems---as far as I can find---undocumented by Apple, referenced only as derived by users via [runtime introspection](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers).

An example follows below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    @IBAction func showAlert(sender: UIButton) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Foo", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        /* attributed string for alertController message */
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bar Bar Bar!")

        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(),
            range: NSRange(location:0,length:3))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(),
            range: NSRange(location:4,length:3))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(),
            range: NSRange(location:8,length:3))

        alertController.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

        /* action: OK */
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Producing the following result:

[image]

Comment: Does UIAlertAction also have "attributedTitle" ?  I would like to specify the font and size of the Actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with UIAlertController (UIAlertView is deprecated).  UIAlertController accepts an Optional String for the `title` and `message` parameters (see [Apple's Documentation on UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)).

In order to use multiple colors in a line of text, you'll need to use `NSAttributedString` (here's a good [NSAttributedString Tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/)).

Since String can't hold any attributes, you won't be able to use NSAttributedString on the UIAlertController.  You will have to create your own modal ViewController with a NSAttributedString label in order to display what you are asking for.

Comment: You can actually use attributed strings for `UIAlertController`, making use of KVC and key `attributedMessage`.