# How to get font size of UIAlertView message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertview, uifont

I am adding a accessoryView in UIAlertView. accessoryView will have label with some text. I want to give label same font as UIAlertView's message font. how to get font style and font size of UIAlertView message

[image]

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635414/change-font-size-for-uialertview-in-ios7

Comment: is not possible bro, if you need anything like this go for custom alert

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS8+... `UIAlertController` is that you need to use since.

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately it is impossible to change the textField font, buttons text color . etc.
Clearly mention in Apple's document.

[UIAlertView_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

The only solution is

1) Use UIView as Custom alertview or

2) There are lots of customised alertview available on Github with awsome animation and etc.
    Like,
   - [ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)

- [DTAlertView](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=custom%20alertview%20github%20ios)

and lots of just search on [Google Alertview](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=custom%20alertview%20github%20ios)

Comment: As holex writes in his comments to the question, `UIAlertView` is deprecated, and `UIAlertController` should be used instead. The latter allows for attributed strings in the alert title as well as message, so you can change font/colours in these as you wish, see e.g. [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141400/how-to-change-color-of-single-letters-or-one-word-in-line#comment58286120_35141400).

Answer (score 0):

You must to create your custom Alert based on UIView.

Apple provide [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) "as-is" it doesn't support subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

They are predefined system font 12. I think you need not to change anything to get that font.